# How can I improve a page with a year change system?

Tags: usability, buttons, select

I'm trying to deal with the UX of a page containing a year change system (see current design below).

[image: Current design - Step 1]
[image: Current design - Step 2]
[image: Current design - Step 3]

I received some feedback and learned that users might have difficulty finding how to change the year. As a result, I added a message that disappears when the **"I understood"** button is clicked. However, it seems that this solution is still insufficient.

[image: Current design - Step 4]

So, my question is: how could I make this *"year change system"* easier to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the <kbd>Settings</kbd> button.

Since the user is in the current year and you want them to change to the next or previous, the logic is adding <kbd>Previous</kbd> and <kbd>Next</kbd> buttons near the title:

[image]

Comment: That's actually not a bad idea and I kinda like it ! I think that I'm gonna consider both of your and @Devin answer. I think that I'm gonna try to setup an A/B testing with these two answers and see the results. But first, I'll start by asking some of the users that gave me the feedbacks which one they think will be the best.

Answer (score 0):

I think the feedback you received is correct. I would never have imagined that you could change the year based on a button with a *cog* icon. Additionally, if these are the actual proportions, that element appears to be completely disconnected from the main elements and is far from view.

Another complicating factor is your breadcrumb. Although your visual hierarchy is appropriate and most people will likely read the title **"My page - 2023/2024"** first, if your proportions are accurate, some individuals may read the breadcrumb first and focus on it.

Considering these points, I would recommend something like the following:

[image]

Comment: Do we need to show the year in both the title and the dropdown? It seems like this could default to the current year and add the dropdown next to the "My Page" title.

Comment: Well, we don't *need* it, but I find it a bit confusing. Consider this site's rankings, which use a similar approach: https://stackexchange.com/leagues/102/year/ux/2023-01-01/. The year selector has no hierarchy at all, and I click on the dropdown because it's the "obvious" thing to do (then I realize it doesn't have the years, and the years selector is a small blue link on a light blue background, but that's another story). To me, mixing the title with the dropdown (I know what you mean and have seen it many times) is a bit confusing. But in the end, it will depend on the OP's testing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'll consider it ! This helps me a lot !